# What will be the procedure to select new mods?

Tags: discussion, moderation

Since our community is in the private beta version. I don't think there are mods, but after the beta test is over and site is launched there will be need of moderators.

How are we going to select moderators, and who is going to select them?

Comment: There will be an election after the site graduates, but until then moderators are identified by the Stack Exchange team about 7 days into the public beta (see [Moderator Pro Tempore](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/)).

Comment: @Aurora0001 Thanks, btw what is the criteria for becoming a mod.

Comment: I hope it doesn't take as long is it did over in 3D Printing SE. But, there will be a request/election for volunteers on Meta and Pro Tempore Moderators will be selected by staff.

Comment: @ChinmayaB: For the pro tem moderators, the list just says: reasonably active, shows interest in community-building, leads by example and follows the [Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/). For the elected moderators later in the site, I assume there will be some badge requirements but I can't say for sure.

Comment: @Aurora0001, usually the min req for elected mods is 300 rep.  On SO it's a good bit higher and there are badge requirements, but on newly graduated sites, there is no badge requirement.

Answer (score 7):

Around [7 days into the public beta](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/), the Stack Exchange team will pick ([most likely three](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134978/how-many-pro-tem-moderators-are-chosen-always-three)) *pro tempore moderators*:

> This is a temporary, short-term appointment. Moderators Pro Tem focus and expedite the essential needs of each new site. By the end of Beta, the community will be better suited to hold their own elections.

At the moment, the community isn't big enough to hold a proper election, but after *graduation* (when IoT exits beta) there will be a democratic election.

The pro tempore moderators will be expected to:

- be relatively active
- be interested in community-building (meta activity is good!)
- lead by example
- follow the [Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).

When the election begins later in the site's lifetime, the goal is simply **get the most votes**!

Also, a note on the timespans: pro tem moderators are *temporary* and remain for the period of the beta, whereas elected moderators keep their position forever*.

** Unless they step down or are removed by the Stack Exchange team (which would only happen in extreme cases).*

Comment: Great points!  Just one note: the article you referenced said, "Pro Tem appointments will begin about two weeks after the site is created."

Comment: @anonymous2 that's odd - earlier in the text it says "That's why I am in the process of identifying and organizing a team of provisional Moderators from within each community (about three per site, starting about seven days into the public Beta)"

Comment: You're right.  Funny, I guess weeks are only 3 1/2 days now.  Seemed like they were passing faster than they used to.  ;)